# Chrome Extension: How to send data from Panel Window to Popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on Chrome extension which on clicking extension Icon popsup a window(`popup.html`) which contain button for Video Play. Upon clicking of the button opens another button which is created by using `window.create` of type `panel`. Upon clicking of PLAY button on `popup.html` does following:

- Make a DIV enabled
- Create new window by calling `window.create` with name `mypanel.html`. It uses `panel.js` to make ajax call and DOM changes functions.
- Make an Ajax call, get data and play Video

Now thing is, the data I am getting via AJAX call in `panel.js`. I want to send that data back to `pop.html` which itself is using file `popup.js`. **How can I send data from panel window to back to Popup Window**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard method of communicating between parts of the extension is described in [Messaging documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

However, you need to keep in mind that as soon as a popup is closed, it is unloaded and the JavaScript context is destroyed along with it. So it cannot receive messages when closed and will lose all state when reopened.

There are two solutions to this:

1. You could employ a [background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) to hold state (if set to be persistent) and route messages between parts of the extension, e.g. a popup can request the current state when opening. *This is an old-school solution.*
2. If all you need is to pass/persist some data, you can easily employ [`chrome.storage.local`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) to do it. You can save data with `panel.js` and react to changes with [`chrome.storage.onChanged` event](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#event-onChanged). The extra bonus is that when a popup reopens, it can simply read the storage to build its initial state.

Comment: I had opted for #2. Thanks:)